# unmarshaling list of xml elements to list using XmlAdapter

Tags: java, xml, java-8, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a list of customer in xml as below

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>product1</name>
        <id>c123</id>
            <customer>
                <name>customer1</name>
                <id>c1</id>
                <dob>10/10/23</dob>
                ....
            </customer>
            <customer>
                <name>customer2</name>
                <id>c2</id>
                <dob>10/10/23</dob>
                ....
            </customer>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>product2</name>
        <id>c123</id>
        <customer>
            <name>customer3</name>
            <id>c3</id>
            <dob>10/10/23</dob>
            ....
        </customer>
        <customer>
            <name>customer4</name>
            <id>c4</id>
            <dob>10/10/23</dob>
            ....
        </customer>
    </product>
</products>
```

to map this I have a custom object

```
public class Product {
   private String name;
   private String id;

   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter (CustomerAdapter.class)
   @XmlElement(name="customer")
   private Map<String, Customer> customerMap;

   setter()/getter()
}

public class Customer {
   private String name;
   private String id;
   private String dob;

   setter()/getter()
}
```

I need to convert this to map of  where key is the id and Customer as value, So that its better to get customer details froma map than a list. In order to do the conversions I wrote an adapter

```
public class CustomerAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Customer, Map<String, Customer>> {

    Map<String, Customer> customerMap = new HashMap<> ( );

    @Override
    public Map<String, Customer> unmarshal(Customer customer) {
        if (null != customer) {
            tagMap.put (customer.getId ( ), customer);
        }
        return customerMap ;
    }

    @Override
    public PublicationTagDto marshal(Map<String, Customer> customerMap) {
        return customerMap.values ().iterator ().next ();
    }

}
```

The problem here is for this I am getting the list of all the customer for all the products. basically for product1 I am getting list of all customer 1 2 3 4. Similarly for product 2 I am getting list of all tree customers 1 2 3 4 . What I need it product1 customer 1 2, product 2 customer 3 4, Basically need to initiate  CustomerAdapter for each person object. The problem here is CustomerAdapter is getting initialized once, I need it to initialize for every product object.

Please help here.

Comment: shouldn't your key be productName in that case?

Comment: Hi @Vinay I have put up a sample xml, using productName as a key wont solve the problem, I have to get the Adapter right.